# Getting Field name inside a struct

Tags: go, pointers, struct, types

I have written a program to retrieve the names of fields inside a struct, and it works perfectly fine. However, when it comes to a pointer of struct inside a struct, it doesn't work.

https://go.dev/play/p/pHrNRhfZSM4

while checking type pointer struct its shows "Ptr" using reflect package  but when I do Elem() it says  is there any way to solve this?

I just want to get every field name with "encr" tag in MAP.

Comment: When you initialize a struct with an empty list of fields, i.e. `Gadget{}`, then any of its pointer fields will be `nil` by default, since `nil` is the __zero value__ for pointer types. And your code traverses the pointer fields ONLY when they are not nil (e.g. you are using `if !field.IsNil() { ...`). So, given the zero-value input, your code basically never traverses the pointer fields. Since you seem to care only about the field tags and not actual field values, your code should not be traversing `relfect.Value` but instead `reflect.Type`, then you don't need to care about nil pointers.

Comment: "retrieve the names of fields inside a struct" there are legitimate uses of `reflect` but they are rare.  make sure you're not using `reflect` to coerce Go's strict type system into behaving like a dynamic typed language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work with types instead of values:

```
func getEncFields(t reflect.Type, list map[string]int) {
    // Dereference pointer types.
    for t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        t = t.Elem()
    }
    // Look for tags in struct fields.
    if t.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
        for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
            field := t.Field(i)
            tag := field.Tag.Get("bson")
            if containsTag(tag, "encr") {
                list[getFieldName(field, tag)]++
            }
            getEncFields(field.Type, list)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how to call it:

```
listOfEncTags := make(map[string]int)
getEncFields(reflect.TypeOf(Gadget{}), listOfEncTags)
fmt.Println(listOfEncTags)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/5JsOil-P-RH